# Error in deploying class using vs code "Error deploying or retrieving source"

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, salesforce-cli

"Error deploying or retrieving source: The file or directory that you tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a package directory that's specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Add this location to your "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or directory. For details about sfdx-project.json, see: [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm%22) I am using Salesforce CLI extension version v58.9.1

I am trying to deploy a class using right click and deploy to org option but i encounter error

Answer (score 0):

> Open sfdx-project.json and add your current package path to the package directory as below:
> the relative path name should be the package directory where all package components exist.

```
{
     "packageDirectories": [
      {
         "path": "force-app",    
         "default": true    
      },
      {
         "path": "relative path name of package directory",
      }

   ],
   "namespace": " ",
   "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
   "sourceApiVersion": "58.0"
}
```